# How to use Symfony 2.5 Translation Component

Tags: php, symfony, translation, translate

I use example from documentation http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/translation/introduction.html

```
public function mytestAction()
{

    $this->get('session')->set('_locale', 'fr_FR');
    $this->get('request')->setLocale('fr');

    $translator = $this->get('translator');

    $translator->addLoader('array', new \Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\ArrayLoader());

    $translator->addResource('array', array(
        'Hello World!' => 'Bonjour',
    ), 'fr_FR');

    $Bonjour = $translator->trans('Hello World!');

    echo $Bonjour; exit;// I get Hello World

}
```

What do I wrong?

May be a problem with Symfony 2.5 Translation Component?

Comment: What is the default locale?

Comment: default locale english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding the locale in your code.

Change `$this->get('request')->setLocale('fr');` to `$this->get('request')->setLocale('fr_FR');`